# What is the refractive index of blood serum?

Tags: refraction, birefringence

I'm looking for the refractive index of the blood containing the antibodies of covid-19.

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe that it would change to a measurable extent? Antibodies are complex proteins, and there are likely many different antibodies circulating in your system at any given time.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a question about physics

Answer (score 2):

In a word, no. The concentration would be orders of magnitude too low to be detectable that way.

Comment: While I completely agree with your answer, I still wonder how to be certain about it. Serum levels of immunoglobulins are on the order of hundreds of mg/dl, which could well have optical effects. The antibody diversity may on the other hand be up to $10^{18}$, making detecting the presence of a few antibody strains among the rest infeasible. So maybe a signal-to-noise argument could make the no a bit firmer.

Comment: @AndersSandberg But then one would have to quantify the noise and justify that number. I think "orders of magnitude too low" covers that base as well as it can be usefully covered for such an uninformed question.